# Swaping Bits in 32bit numbers considering two nibles and strings reverse

Tags: bit-manipulation

This is interview question.Please tell me answer for this.

number-10010011.now we need to swap first two bits to 3rd and 4th positions.
output-10110001.
same number but output-10000111.

2)this is qualcom interview.
now we need to reverse a string.

output-interview qualcom is this.

but with out using strtok library.
Please tell me how to do this programes.
i searched in internet but not got proper answers.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of asking others to do your job for you, perhaps you should study up and learn how to answer the questions yourself...

Comment: If you want to be a programmer, you should really try to figure out these yourself -- these aren't difficult things to do if you know the basics.

Answer (score 0):

The first question in bitshift operations:

```
right = 10010011 & 00000011 // right = 00000011
left = 10010011 & 00110000 // left = 00010000
fix = 10010011 & 11001100 // fix = 10000000 

right = right << 4 // right = 00110000
left = left >> 4 // left = 00000001
result = fix | right | left // result = 10110001
```

so what I did was to separate the bits into those that dont Change (from left: 1,2, 5,6) a left Group (3 and 4) and a right Group (7 and 8) then shift the left Group to 7 and 8 and right to 3 and 4. and then Combine fix, left and right again.

string Inversion can also be done pretty straight Forward, just iterate the string swapping chars:

```
word = "hello world"
for(int i = 0; i <= word.Length/2; i++)
   help = word[i]
   word[i] = word[word.Length-i]
   word[word.Length-i] = help
```

// dello worlh, dlllo woreh, ...

For words inversion you can use that algorithm(revert(string)) as well:

```
reverted = revert(input)
words = reverted.split(" ")
for(int i=0; i<words.Length; i++)
  words[i] = revert(words[i])
words.join(" ")
```

Comment: Hi Tobias Maslowski,

Thank you for great answer.

I have one doubt in string reverse question.

Ex:"Qualcom interview location"This is string taken as example

Now output like this:location interview Qualcom.

Please tell me programe for this with out using strtok function.

Comment: That's a slightly different problem then what you asked for, which was string reversion - what you seem to require is an algorithm to invert the order of the words from a string. If thats so you can use the string reversion algorithm to revert the string, then get the words by splitting/tokenizing/... and invert the words with the same string reversion algorithm. I edited my reply accordingly